# Trying to merge 4 of my functions into 1 but running into problems

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am making an R package that streamlines my microarray analysis. It is driving me mad. I have 4 main functions at work, I try to combine them into one. Individually they work but together I get the following error.

```
Error in topTable(normfit, number = 1e+05, adjust = "BH", lfc = 1) : 
fit must be an MArrayLM object
```

The problem which I think is happening, since each function uses an input of what comes before it , the 3rd function does not complete running before the last one starts.

```
function (mydir, group, design, contrast) 
{
    lonoan(mydir)
    filterc(normData)
    normfit(normData, group, design, contrast)
    results(normfit)
}
```

The error comes from my results function.

```
function (normfit) 
{
    probeset.list <- topTable(normfit, number = 1e+05, adjust = "BH", 
        lfc = 1)
    Symbol <- getSYMBOL(rownames(probeset.list), "hugene20sttranscriptcluster.db")
    results <- cbind(probeset.list, Symbol)
    assign("results", results, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

At the end of the run the normfit variable is in the global environment and if I run the function again it works. This is driving me mad. Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Check the normData in normfit. is it changed in filterc or not?

Comment: Why are you not doing functional programing? Side effects, i.e., your use of `assign`, are bad. Let your function return `results`.

Comment: I would assume yes because if go through the list of functions by pressing enter manually it works without a problem. It is just when I combined it like about that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Roland because I need to use the variable down the road, if I used return it doesn't get stored in the global environment.

Comment: You need to reconsider and redesign how your objects are passed between your functions. You've encountered one reason why what you are doing now is bad: scoping problems.

Comment: Alright, @Roland do you have any good resources that I can use to look into that

Comment: Sorry, not on the top of my head. But it's actually easy: Everything needed inside the function should be passed as an argument and the result should be returned (and possibly assigned with `<-` where the function is called). There are exceptions, but this should be the general approach.